# How to edit Firefox bookmarks with regex in Notepad++

Tags: html, regex, firefox, replace

I need to combine multiple bookmarks files and reduce the size, but I don't know how to use regular expression.

**I want to:**

1. Delete every line that starts with `<DD>`
2. Delete the following HTML tags and the (unknown) text between the
   qoutes: `ICON_URI="..."`, `ICON="..."`, and `LAST_CHARSET="..."`
3. Replace the text between `>` and `</A>`
4. Delete duplicate lines
5. Sort lines alphabetically

Comment: And have you tried anything?? You need to show some effort on your end before you can expect any from our end...

Comment: Each one of these things require a separate action. So you have 5 separate questions. And I think `ICON_URI="..."` would be an attribute, nor really a tag.

Comment: Of course I tried. I actually figured all this out a few years ago but I forgot it, and somehow I can't even comprehend regex anymore. I don't need all 5 questions answered. I would appreciate even just the basics. If someone knows how to answer any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Tested in Notepad++, for other tools it may not work. Also for some strange cases it could not work in Notepad++ as well

```html
1. ^<DD>.*?$ - replace with empty string
2.ICON_URI="[^"]*" - replace with empty string
3.(<a[^>]+>).+?</a> - replace with \1 </a>
4. This is hard to do with regex, you can use grouping and repetition, but I'm not advanced in that
5. Use excel or other similar tool and order there, much easier
```